# Partial View Validation Error getting trigger on partial view on view get call itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that has two partial views one is for create and other is to list items I am using a view model as the model of the main view

My View is as follows

```
@model Project.Web.Areas.Administrator.Models.VFranchise

<!-- content starts -->
<div class=" large-10 medium-10 small-10 columns band">
    <div class="row no-margin">
        <div class="content-head ">
            <!--breadcrumbs-->
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "GetAll")</li>
                <li>></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Franchise", "GetAll")</li>
                <li>></li>
                <li><a href="">Create New Franchise</a></li>
                <li>></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        @{Html.RenderAction("CreateFranchise", "Franchise", Model.Franchise);}
        @{Html.RenderAction("ListAllFranchise", "Franchise", Model.Franchisees);}

    </div>
</div>
```

My View Model is as below

```
public class VFranchise
{
    public Franchaise Franchise { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Franchaise> Franchisees { get; set; }
}
```

My Partial View to create is as follows

```
 @model Project.BAL.Models.Master.Franchaise

<div class="general-wrapper">
    <!--content box-->
    <div class="general-head">
        <h2 class="no-margin">Create New Franchise</h2>
        <div class="general-icons-org">
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Franchise", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="minus-wrapper">
            <div class="org-general-wrapper">
                <div class="org-wrapper">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-2">
                        <li>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="inner">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="inner">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="inner">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="inner">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="inner">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpiryDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="inner">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpiryDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpiryDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="inner">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="inner">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, new List<SelectListItem>{
                                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Active", Value = "1" },
                                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Deactive", Value = "2" },
                                     }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </li>



                        <li>
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                            <div class="inner">
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="req-wrapper">
                        <p>* required field</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="edit-wrapper">
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "GetAll")
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Controller for main view

```
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
     return View(new VFranchise());
 }
```

Here is my Post method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Franchaise model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.FranchaiseId = Guid.NewGuid();
            model.Status = Convert.ToInt32(model.Status);
            model.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            _FranchaiseServices.Create(model);
            return RedirectToAction("GetAll");
        }
        else {
            var _model = new VFranchise();
            _model.Franchise = model;
            return View(_model);
        }

    }
```

Here are my Partial View Control

```
public PartialViewResult CreateFranchise(Franchaise model)
{
  return PartialView(model);
}

public PartialViewResult _ListFranchiseByExpiry(string id)
{
    int _id = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    var items = _FranchaiseServices.GetAllFranchiseByExpiry(_id);
    return PartialView(items);
}
```

The issue is I am getting validation errors on HTTP get call of create itself.

If I do this

```
public PartialViewResult CreateFranchise()
{
  return PartialView(new Franchaise());
}
```

I don't get any validation error on post as well, Can someone suggest me what am I doing wrong here please. Thanks !

Comment: You get validation errors on the `CreateFranchise(Franchaise model)` method because you passing an invalid model to the method and because it contains validation attributes, the `DefaultModelBinder` adds `ModelState` errors

Comment: But if I dont do it like that I was getting no error even after HTTP post ?

Comment: Your approach is wrong and you need to use a view model(s) - view models do not contain properties which are data models. I will add an answer in 30 min or so.

Comment: Appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get validation errors on the `CreateFranchise(Franchaise model)` method because the model you pass to the method contains validation attributes and its values are invalid (e.g. you might have a `[Required]` attribute on a `string` property, but the value if `null), so the`DefaultModelBinder`adds`ModelState` errors which are then displayed in the view.

View models should not contain properties that are data models, at least for editing) and it should be

```
public class FranchaiseVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    .... // copy other properties of Franchaise that you want to edit
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Franchaise> Franchaises { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method for the view

```
FranchaiseVM model = new FranchaiseVM()
{
    StatusList = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Text="Active", Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem{ Text="Deactive", Value = "2" }
    },
    Franchaises = .... // your query for populating the collection
};
return View(model)
```

and in the main view

```
@model FranchaiseVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Franchise", FormMethod.Post))
{
    .... your form controls
}
@{ Html.RenderAction("ListAllFranchise", "Franchise", Model.Franchisees); }
```

and in the POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FranchaiseVM viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.StatusList = ... as per GET method
        model.Franchaises = ... as per GET method
       return View(viewModel);
    }
    // Initialize data model and set its properties
    Franchaise dataModel = new Franchaise()
    {
        Name = viewModel.Name,
        .... // map other properties
        Status = viewModel.Status, // not sure why you need to convert it
        StartDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    _FranchaiseServices.Create(dataModel);
    return RedirectToAction("GetAll");
}
```

Side note: There seems no reason to use `RenderAction()` to generate the existing items in this case. A better approach would be to create a `DisplayTemplate` in `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Franchaise.cshtml`

```
@model Franchaise
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
....
```

and in the main view use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Franchaises)` which will generate the html for each item in the collection.

Comment: Forgot to mention in the answer, that the reason you get no validation in the 2nd example you tried, is because all you doing is generating a new instance of `Franchaise` but its not passing the `ModelState` values/errors so there is nothing in `ModelState`